# Criando um slider com JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Fala comunidade, tudo bem?!

Estou criando um slider usando o JQuery e não estou conseguindo mais avançar. No exemplo que criei eu não consigo alterar as imagens clicando no menu inferior direito. Quais instruções do código estão incorretas?

Além do evento de clique, gostaria também que as imagens trocassem automaticamente preservando a ordem de clique.

Fiquem a vontade para sugestões e críticas em relação ao código tanto como semântica e boas práticas.

```js
$(function() {

  /* Main Slider */
  const $slider = $('.main-slider');
  const $images = $slider.find('.slider-images img');
  const $dots = $slider.find('.slider-dot-navigation .dot');

  $dots.click(function() {
    const $dot = $(this);
    const dotIndex = $dot.index();
    const $image = $($images.get(dotIndex));

    $images.not($image).fadeOut(700);
    $image.fadeIn(700);

    $dots.removeClass('selected');
    $dot.addClass('selected');
  });

});
```

```css
/* Main Slider */

.main-slider {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.main-slider>.slider-images {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-slider>.slider-images>figure>img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  height: 100%;
}

.main-slider>.slider-images>.slider-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.main-slider>.slider-dot-navigation {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 80px;
}

.main-slider>.slider-dot-navigation>.dot {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.main-slider>.slider-dot-navigation>.dot.selected {
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
}

.main-slider>.slider-dot-navigation>li:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-slider>.slider-dot-navigation>li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="slider" class="main-slider">
  <div class="slider-images">
    <figure>
      <img alt="" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1001/800/600">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img alt="" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1002/800/600">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img alt="" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1004/800/600">
    </figure>
    <div class="slider-content">
      <h1>SLIDER</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ol class="slider-dot-navigation">
    <li class="dot selected"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Comment: Não está aparecendo nenhum menu.

Comment: O menu não aparece porque o css não está bem codificado, o ideal seria utilizar a propriedade `background` ao invés de usar elementos `img` para um slider?

Comment: Acho que img seria melhor pq vc pode carregar a imagem só quando ela aparecer. No caso do background não daria ou se dá ficaria mais complicado.

Comment: Seu código está funcionando, está trocando as imagens no click certinho (você acha que não está pois as imagens são todas iguais) você só precisa remover a classe `selected` do primeiro `li.dot` e por no último para ficar coerente. Com relação a passar sozinho você pode fazer algo com `setInterval` ou `setTimeOut` para e dar um `.click()` no dot da vez e se for o último dar `.click()` no primeiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Além do evento de clique, gostaria também que as imagens trocassem automaticamente preservando a ordem de clique.

Este exemplo pode te ajudar. Fiz os comentários no próprio código.

```js
$(function() {

  /* Main Slider */
  const $slider = $('.main-slider');
  const $images = $slider.find('.slider-images img');
  const $dots = $slider.find('.slider-dot-navigation .dot');

  $dots.click(function() {
  
    //interrompe o timeout em andamento
    Auto.stop();
  
    const $dot = $(this);
    const dotIndex = $dot.index();
    const $image = $($images.get(dotIndex));

    $images.not($image).fadeOut(700);
    
    //após o fadeIn reinicia o timeout
    $image.fadeIn(700, Auto.start());

    $dots.removeClass('selected');
    $dot.addClass('selected');          
    
  });
  
  //objeto para automatizar o clique
  const Auto = {
  
    interval: null,

    f: _ => {

        let next = $dots.filter('.selected').next('li');

        if (next.length === 0) { next = $dots.filter(':first'); }
       
        next.click();  
        
      },
  
    start: _ => {  
      
      Auto.interval = setTimeout(_ => {Auto.f()}, 1500);    
            
      },
      
    stop: _ => clearTimeout(Auto.interval)     
  
  };
  
  //Iniciar
  Auto.start();
  
});
```

```css
/* Main Slider */

.main-slider {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.main-slider>.slider-images {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-slider>.slider-images>figure>img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  height: 100%;
}

.main-slider>.slider-images>.slider-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.main-slider>.slider-dot-navigation {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 80px;
}

.main-slider>.slider-dot-navigation>.dot {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.main-slider>.slider-dot-navigation>.dot.selected {
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
}

.main-slider>.slider-dot-navigation>li:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-slider>.slider-dot-navigation>li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="slider" class="main-slider">
  <div class="slider-images">
    <figure>
      <img alt="" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1001/800/600">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img alt="" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1002/800/600">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img alt="" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1004/800/600">
    </figure>
    <div class="slider-content">
      <h1>SLIDER</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ol class="slider-dot-navigation">
    <li class="dot selected"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
  </ol>
</section>
```